# How to enforce foreign key constraints in a self-referencing association?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Assuming the most simple example:

```
var Person = sequelize.define('Person', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
});

Person.hasMany(Person, { as: 'Children', foreignKeyConstraint: true });
```

If we `sequelize.sync` this, we get a `ChildrenPersons` join table that has a two-column primary key, formed by `PersonId` and `ChildrenId`, but no foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE `ChildrenPersons` (
  `PersonId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ChildrenId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PersonId`,`ChildrenId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

How can I make `PersonId` and `ChildrenId` `CONSTRAIN`ed foreign keys, referencing `Persons.id` ?

I tried [manually creating the join table](https://gist.github.com/mihai-rotaru/7233452#file-sequelize-self-referencing-js), but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I am not really familiar with sequelize but I know you can use it to directly issue SQL queries and commands using `sequelize.query`

So if you just want to create the two tables with the foreign key constraints here is the appropriate SQL (Please note that this is SQLite dialect - notice the lack of datetime)

```
CREATE TABLE Persons(
    id integer primary key, 
    name text);
CREATE TABLE ChildrenPersons(
    personId integer not null, 
    childrenId integer not null, 
    createdAt integer not null,  
    updatedAt integer not null, 
    primary key(personId,childrenId), 
    foreign key(personId) references Persons(id), 
    foreign key(childrenId) references Persons(id));
```

I hope this helps

**EDIT**

The following code will create the table using sequelize lingo (Confirmed to be working with sequelize 1.7.9) :

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
sequelize = new Sequelize('test','','',
            {
            dialect: 'sqlite',
                storage: 'test.db'
            })
var Person = sequelize.define('Person', {name: Sequelize.STRING})
var PersonChildren = sequelize.define('PersonChildren',
        {
            PersonId: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                references: Person,
                referencesKey: 'id',
                primaryKey: true
            },
            ChildrenId: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                references: Person,             
                referencesKey: 'id',
                primaryKey: true
            }
        })
sequelize.sync({force: true}).complete(function(err){
    if(!!err){
        console.log('Error: ',err)
    }else
    {
        console.log('All OK')
    }   
})
```

Loot at he following Sequelize documentation article for enforcing foreign key constraints:
http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/associations

Comment: OP is using `Sequelize`. Answer doesn't use `sequelize`

Comment: @Shamoon -Actually it does using sequelize.query. But hey you don't have to like it even though it solves the problem. I didn't answer this question to get your bounty. I answered it to help someone who didn't know how to enforce the foreign key constraints he was looking for and for the benefits of others. I pointed him to the way he can do it using sequelize. You don't have to like it but it really doesn't warrant a vote down.

Comment: I believe by doing it your way, the association wouldn't be there with sequelize. Which is part of what the OP wants to achieve.

Comment: @Shamoon - See the new edit, hopefully it will make you happy