# Rich self-association with foreign key constraints in Sequelize with PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using SequelizeJS with PostgreSQL..

I have a table `units`. I want a table `unit_relations` with columns `unit1_id`, `unit2_id`, `type`. Both `unit1_id` and `unit2_id` should have foreign key constraints to `units.id` such that any time a unit is deleted, any rows of `unit_relations` referencing that unit (as either `unit1` or `unit2`) are deleted as well.

In Sequelize, I want `unit2` to be mapped to `Relation` and `unit1` to be mapped to `ReverseRelation`; e.g. the row

```
          units                         unit_relations
------------+---------------   ----------+----------+-------
relation_id | reverce_rel_id    unit1_id | unit2_id |  type
------------+---------------   ----------+----------+--------
            |                         11 |       43 | parent
```

would be fetched by `unit1.getRelations()` and `unit2.getReverseRelations()`.

I am having difficulty getting Sequelize to respect my column names (it wants to use `relation_id` and `reverse_relation_id`) or create the foreign keys.

Comment: The foreign key part of my question is also found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686144/how-to-enforce-foreign-key-constraints-in-a-self-referencing-association?rq=1, though that doesn't deal with the column naming

Comment: `Relation` and `ReverseRelation` are in **units** table?

Comment: Юрий, что вы подразумеваете под фразой `to respect my column names` - **уважать название моих колонок** ?

Comment: @khaljava yes, they both reference things in the unit table. When I say "respect my column names", I mean I want the columns in `unit_relations` to be named `unit1_id` and `unit2_id`; when Sequelize generates the columns, it's calling them `relation_id` or `reverse_relation_id`.

Answer (score 2):

I still do not fully understand all the relationships between tables. Try to describe it using simple examples rather than abstract concepts. Like

```
//Mary Had A Little Lamb
Marry.hasOne(Lamp)
```

But from what I understand, you can do so:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize(.... {
    // your pg db settinds 
});

var Unit = sequelize.define('Unit', {});

var UnitRel = sequelize.define('UnitRel', {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
});

// Create in Unit table columns 'relation_id' and 'rev_rel_id'
UnitRel.hasOne(Unit, {foreignKey: 'relation_id', as: 'Relation'});
UnitRel.hasOne(Unit, {foreignKey: 'rev_rel_id', as: 'RevRelation'});

// Create in UnitRel table columns 'unit1_id' and 'unit2_id'
UnitRel.belongsTo(Unit, {foreignKey: 'unit1_id', as: 'Unid_1'});
UnitRel.belongsTo(Unit, {foreignKey: 'unit2_id', as: 'Unid_2'});



Unit.sync({force: true}).success(function() {
    UnitRel.sync({force: true}).success(function() {
        console.log('TABLES CREATED');
    });
});
```

and then find some `UnitRel` and stretch dependent fields

```
UnitRel.find({
  where: {id: 1}, 
    include:[
      {model: Unit, as: 'Uid_1'},
      {model: Unit, as: 'Uid_2'}
    ]
}).success(function(match) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify);
});
```